# Exclude folders from Document Library displayed using PnP Search Results

Tags: pnp

We are building a new intranet in SPO.  I have a document library with many folders and documents.  I am using the PnP Search Result with the following

```
{searchTerms}
Path:https://TENENT.sharepoint.com/sites/SITENAME/Shared%20Documents
```

I am getting a result like this

```
File1
Folder
File2 
Folder
```

I have tried filtering out the folders using the Refinement Filter with something like `not(FileType:equals("folder"))` but that hasn't worked either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `contentclass:STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary` to the query template.

Comment: This works.  It also removes ASPX files (which I am deleting anyway).

Comment: I found that using `-ContentType:folder` removes the folders in the Document Library but the base Document Library name still persisted in the results.   Adding `-contentclass: STS_List_DocumentLibrary` removes that.

Comment: Happy to hear it works for you. Thanks for the updated info!

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer the PnP Modern Search GitHub website https://github.com/microsoft-search/pnp-modern-search/discussions/2124

The accepted answer is here https://github.com/microsoft-search/pnp-modern-search/discussions/2124#discussioncomment-2863464, which is

> In the query template you can use this condition `-ContentTypeId:0x0120* IsDocument:1 Path:"https://<your_library_path>/*"`

I changed my query to

```
{searchTerms}
Path:https://TENENT.sharepoint.com/sites/SITENAME/Shared%20Documents/*
-ContentTypeId:0x0120* IsDocument:1
```

and the result is

```
File1
Folder
File2 
Folder
```